# automatic photo slider with fade in and out animation- javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, slider

I did a 5 images slider that changes images automatically within a few seconds in a loop.
I want fade out and in animations before and after changing each image.
This is my code:

HTML:

`<div id="slider">
        <img id="bigImage" src="img/Traffic1.jpg">
</div>`

JS:

```
var imageArray = ["img/Traffic1.jpg", "img/Traffic2.jpg", "img/Traffic3.jpg",
        "img/Traffic4.jpg","img/Traffic5.jpg"]; 
        var imageIndex = 0;
        function changeImageByTimer() {
        document.getElementById("bigImage").src = imageArray[imageIndex];

        imageIndex++;

            if (imageIndex > 4) {
                imageIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        var imgTimer = setInterval(changeImageByTimer, 3000);
```

I cant change the html code only the javascript. I prefer to use only javascript.
Any suggestions?

Comment: animating opacity is probably the easiest way to get this effect. check out this article for native JS/CSS animations. http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/

Comment: @bencripps Thank you very much but I find it hard to understand how i use it in my code. Can you help?

Comment: are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: @bencripps I am but i don't know how to work with jQuery, I don't know how to combine jQuery and Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's a JavaScript implementation that is as simple as it gets. You're going to want to read up on jQuery, and specifically animations if you want to customize this even a little bit.

Here is the working jsBin: http://jsbin.com/pozutidu/5/edit?html,js,output

Essentially, the only important aspect of this is:

```
  bigImage.animate({opacity: .1 }, function() { 

      $(this).attr('src', imageArray[imageIndex]) 

  });
```

So what is happening here, is you're selected the Img, and animating it's opacity. Once the opacity has reached .1, the callback function takes the same element and relplaces the img.src. This gives off the appearance of an image fading in and out.

References to look at: http://jquery.com/, http://api.jquery.com/animate/

**before you can run this, you must include a link to the jQuery source file**

< script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" >< /script>

Answer (score 0):

```
/* HTML Code */
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="image1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="image2.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
   </div>
</div>

/* CSS code */
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}

/* Js Code */
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

Comment: Could you give some more detail as to why you gave the answer you did.  How does it differ or improve on the OP's solution.  It is also a teaching moment here.